# Microsoft Graph .NET Core SDK: Sudden Casting Error

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm using the Microsoft Graph .NET Core SDK to grab all the AAD groups that the current user is a member of. With parameter, "name" being the UPN

```
public List<string> GetUserGroups(string name)
        {
            if (name == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
            }
            
            var groups = new List<string>();
            var userGroups = _graphServiceClient.Users[name].MemberOf.Request().GetAsync().Result;
            bool hasNextPage;
           
            do
            {
                hasNextPage = userGroups.NextPageRequest != null;
                groups.AddRange(userGroups.CurrentPage.Cast<Group>().Select(x => x.DisplayName));

                if (hasNextPage)
                {
                    userGroups = userGroups.NextPageRequest.GetAsync().Result;
                }
            }
            while (hasNextPage);

            return groups;
        }
```

This piece of code was working just fine until very recently, where any attempt to get group information ended with an `InvalidCastException`:

`Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Graph.AdministrativeUnit' to type 'Microsoft.Graph.Group'.`

My code is not even accessing the AdministrativeUnit to cast from.. I did not change anything with the code so I'm not sure what is going on here.

Comment: what's happening is a DirectoryObject with property "ODataType" is being returned with a value of "AdministrativeUnit", not just "Group". So the cast fails. Yes I can filter out ODataType that isn't Group, but surely there is a way to specifically ask for only Group directoryobjects..

Answer (score 0):

You can apply OData casting by appending segment microsoft.graph.group to the request url.

```
public List<string> GetUserGroups(string name)
{
    if (name == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
    }
        
    var groups = new List<string>();
    var requestUrl = _graphServiceClient.Users[name]             
                       .MemberOf
                       .AppendSegmentToRequestUrl("microsoft.graph.group");
    var userGroups = new GraphServiceGroupsCollectionRequest(requestUrl, _graphServiceClient, Enumerable.Empty<Option>())
            .GetAsync().Result;
    bool hasNextPage;
       
    do
    {
        hasNextPage = userGroups.NextPageRequest != null;
        groups.AddRange(userGroups.CurrentPage.Cast<Group>().Select(x => x.DisplayName));

        if (hasNextPage)
        {
            userGroups = userGroups.NextPageRequest.GetAsync().Result;
        }
    }
    while (hasNextPage);

    return groups;
}
```